# Using Regex to replace part of the entire string/expression

Tags: c#, .net, regex, replace

Regex are simple yet complex at times. Stuck to replace an expression having variables, assuming variable is of the following pattern:

```
\w+(\.\w+)*
```

I want to replace all the occurrences of my variable replacing dot (.) because i have to eventually tokenize the expression where tokenizer do not recognize variable having dots. So i thought to replace them with underscore before parsing. After tokenizing however i want to get the variable token with original value.

Expression:

```
(x1.y2.z3 + 9.99) + y2_z1 - x1.y2.z3
```

Three Variables:

```
x1.y2.z3

y2_z1

x1.y2.z3
```

Desired Output:

```
(x1_y2_z3 + 9.99) + y2_z1 - x1_y2_z3
```

- Question 1: How to use Regex replace in this case?
- Question 2: Is there any better way to address above mentioned problem because variable can have underscore so replacing dot with underscore is not a viable solution to get the original variable back in tokens?

Comment: `var output = "(x1.y2.z3 + 9) + y2_z1 - x1.y2.z3".Replace('.', '_');`, or `var output = Regex.Replace("(x1.y2.z3 + 9) + y2_z1 - x1.y2.z3", @"\.", "_");` will replace the dots for you.

Comment: You can just randomly replace periods because you could have a floating point number 123.456.  You have to first parse the statement int elements around the operands +,-,*,/ and then replace the periods in each element.

Comment: True the floating point numbers should not be replaced. Therefore i want to replace variables only in the whole expression.

Comment: Good point @jdweng. Furqan, your pattern `\w+(\.\w+)*` is matching on `9.99`. If you can get your pattern correct and only match on the actual variables, then I think the relevant question is, "How do I replace a character in a string, but only if that character is part of a regex match?".

Comment: Help me in correcting the pattern to identify variables only? I have given my requirements.

Comment: My point is you have to tokenize first and then replace the periods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex pattern seems to work: `[a-zA-Z]+\d+\S+`

To replace a dot found *only* in a match you use MatchEvaluator:

```
    private static char charToReplaceWith = '_';
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string s = "(x1.y2.z3 + 9.99) + y2_z1 - x1.y2.z3";
        Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(s, @"[a-zA-Z]+\d+\S+", new MatchEvaluator(ReplaceDotWithCharInMatch)));
        Console.Read();
    }

    private static string ReplaceDotWithCharInMatch(Match m)
    {
        return m.Value.Replace('.', charToReplaceWith);
    }
```

Which gives this output:
`(x1_y2_z3 + 9.99) + y2_z1 - x1_y2_z3`

I don't fully understand your second question and how to deal with tokenizing variables that already have underscores, but you should be able to choose a character to replace with (i.e., `if (string.Contains('_'))` is `true` then you choose a different character to replace with, but probably have to maintain a dictionary that says "I replaced all dots with underscores, and all underscores with `^`, etc..).

Comment: I liked the idea of using MatchEvaluator. My second question means that variable can have both underscore and dot, e.g. x1_y2.z3 which will be changed to x1_y2_z3. Now how to get my original variable back replacing only the underscore to dot between y2 and z3? Further, if i change my dot to someother special character, tokeznier might not understand this variable because variable can only include alphanumeric and underscore.

Comment: Sounds doable. Need to use the `Match.Index` property in the match evaluator to determine the indices of where the dots were originally, save those indexes to a global list visible by the match evaluator method, then to "de-tokenize" you replace all the indices in the tokenized strings with the original character (dot in this case), using the list to know which indices. I don't have time at the moment to do all of that..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
        string input = "(x1.y2.z3 + 9.99) + y2_z1 - x1.y2.z3";
        string output = Regex.Replace(input, "\\.(?<![a-z])", "_");
```

This will replace only periods which are followed by a letter (a-z).

Comment: Adding an explanation of how this RegEx answers the question will improve your answer for future visitors (this answer was flagged as low-quality).

Answer (score 0):

Use Regex' [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) by making a group that starts with `(?!`

A dot followed by something non-numeric would be as simple as this:

```
// matches any dot NOT followed by a character in the range 0-9
String output = Regex.Replace(input, "\\.(?![0-9])", "_");
```

This has the advantage that while the [0-9] is part of the expression, it is only checked as being *behind* the match, but is not actually part of the match.